# Confused over use of private and public

Tags: java, private

I am getting an error in my code in the line 
    private LinkedList stock.

The error states I have an illegal start of expression, presumably being private? How can I change this to get rid of the error? I get the exact same error if I change it to `public`. Everything in my `stockItem` class is set to `public`, as well.

Any help would be much appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
public class StockList {
{
 private LinkedList<StockItem> stock
        = new LinkedList<StockItem>();


public StockList() {};
```

thanks.

Comment: Your source does not compile

Comment: Can you put your code in its entirety? Right now you have some brackets that don't make sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you've got two opening curly braces:

```
public class StockList { // <<== Here
{ // <<== And here
```

you need to remove one of them in order for this to compile.

Comment: That and it's missing a curly brace at the end as well (Assuming the snippet provided in the original question is the entire class)

Answer (score 3):

As dasblinkenlight said, you have two opening curly braces. You also have no closing curly brace for the StockList class.

```
  public class StockList {
       private LinkedList<StockItem> stock = new LinkedList<StockItem>();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

your private is just fine, it is a curly brace problem.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StockList {
{  <<< Remove this <<<<<
 private LinkedList<StockItem> stock
        = new LinkedList<StockItem>();


public StockList() {};
}  << add this
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare fields on class level

```
class YourClass{
    //class level
    private LinkedList<StockItem> stock = new LinkedList<StockItem>();
    {
        //not here, in initialization block
    }
}
```

So you need to remove one of extra `{` before `private LinkedList<StockItem> stock`

Answer (score 0):

Change to

'private LinkedList stock;

public class StockList() {
       stock =new LinkedList();
}'

and the code should still work.